# Derivation of the polytropic process equation for an adiabatic process

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas, adiabatic

I am trying to derive $$pV^\gamma - p_0V_0^\gamma = 0$$ from the first law of thermodynamics and the ideal gas law. I thought of two seemingly identical ways, which yield different results. Maybe someone can tell me where I went wrong.

For an adiabatic process, there is no heat transfer. $$\delta Q = 0$$
This is substituted into the first law of thermodynamics.
$$ dU = \delta Q + \delta W = \delta W$$
Now the inner energy and mechanical work can be written as
$$ \frac{f}{2}n R dT = - p dV.$$ Interchanging the ideal gas law yields
$$p = \frac{nRT}{V}.$$
Plugging that in gives us
$$ \frac{f}{2}n R dT = - \frac{nRT}{V} dV.$$
Which is equivalent to
$$ \frac{-f}{2} \frac{dT}{T}= \frac{dV}{V}.$$
We can now integrate the whole equation from the initial temperature and volume to the final temperature and volume.
$$ \frac{-f}{2} \int_{T_0}^{T} \frac{dT'}{T'}= \int_{V_0}^{V} \frac{dV'}{V'}.$$
$$ \left(\frac{T}{T_0} \right)^{\frac{-f}{2}} = \frac{V}{V_0}$$
Substituting in the ideal gas law for two different temperatures
$$T_0 = \frac{p_0V_0}{nR}$$
$$T = \frac{pV}{nR}$$
and interchanging gives us the correct result.
$$  \frac{p}{p_0} = \left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right)^{-(\frac{2}{f}+1)} = \left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right)^{-\gamma}$$.

So much for the prelude!

Why is it not possible to use the ideal gas law directly in the first step of the derivation?
The derivative of the ideal gas law with respect to the pressure p reads
$$dpV = nRdT$$
With the help of this derivative, the inner energy can be expressed as
$$dU = \frac{f}{2}n R dT = \frac{f}{2} V dp.$$
If we put this inner energy back into the first law and integrate from initial to final conditions we get
$$dU = \delta W = -pdV = \frac{f}{2}dpV$$
$$\frac{p}{p_0} = \left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right)^{-\frac{2}{f}} = \left( \frac{V}{V_0} \right)^{1-\gamma}$$

This is obviously not the same. I would be rather happy if someone could tell me where I made the mistake, which leads to this contradiction.

Comment: You can, you just differentiated wrong. $PV = Nk_BT \Rightarrow PdV+VdP = Nk_BdT$

Comment: Oh my...
Thank you!